# Generate XML report of JUnit Testcases

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, junit, sonarqube

How can I generate XML report output of my Maven project? 
I am trying to view test coverage report in Sonar but its coming as 0.0% , from the documention

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project

I come to know that we have to give path of JUnit Report.
Can anyone explain what are the entries I have to do in pom.xml to get JUnit reports in XML format?

Comment: Coverage reports are different from surefire junit reports which are just about how the tests were executed (did they pass? how many time did they take). So you should generate a JaCoCo report for the coverage.

Comment: Can you guide me how to generate JaCoCo report ?

Comment: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Usage+of+JaCoCo+with+Java+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking about coverage reports, check out:
http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/

Here is a sample Maven configuration for JaCoCo, you will find the coverage reports in the target/site/jacoco folder:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-check</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <rule>
                                <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                <limits>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>LINE</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <!-- increase this number to enforce a minimum -->
                                        <minimum>0.0</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                </limits>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```